# Is there any benefit to having an auto-incrementing primary key in a MySQL pivot table?

Tags: mysql, performance

Imagine we have three tables in a MySQL database:

- posts
- categories
- category_post

There is a one-to-many relationship between **posts** and **categories** so that a single post may have many categories.

The **category_post** table is the pivot table between **categories** and **posts** and has the following columns:

- id (primary key, auto-incrementing, big integer)
- category_id
- post_id

Let's also imagine that we have 1,000,000 rows in our **category_post** table.

My question is:

Is there any performance benefit to having the **id** column in the **category_post** table or does it just take up extra space?

Comment: If you don't have primary key, InnoDB will make one for its internal use, that means you can't avoid it (and it will be an 8 byte integer). For such purposes (junctions), I personally always have primary key. Reason I do this is so I can actually identify a row properly, even though in 99.9% of cases I might not even query that table manually to see what's in there. However, since apps evolve and needs change - imagine this scenario - you suddenly need a link between your posts and categories for another purpose. Is it not easier to have a single key identifying it opposed to compound one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Posts and categories is probably many-to-many, not one-to-many.

A many-to-many relationship table is best done something like

```
CREATE TABLE a_b (
a_id ... NOT NULL,
b_id ... NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (a_id, b_id),
INDEX(b_id, a_id) -- include this if you need to go both directions
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

With that, you automatically get "clustered" lookups both directions, and you avoid the unnecessary artificial id for the table.

(By the way, N.B., an implicit PK is 6 bytes, not 8.  There is a lengthy post by Jeremy Cole on the topic.)

A one-to-many relationship does not need this extra table.  Instead, have one id inside the other table.  For example, a City table will have the id for the Country in it.

Comment: @AucT - Any ordering would probably come from `a` or `b`, not the many:many mapping table.  I've seen extra columns concerning a relationship, but rarely anything to "order" them.  One exception:  `tags` and `articles`, wherein the mapping table is really aimed at being an [_ordered list_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists).  (Oops - The comment that prompted this, was deleted.)

Answer (score 7):

Having category_id and post_id as a compound primary key will have better performance than having an extra id as a primary key. This is because making it a primary key will also create an [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) on it automatically. If you really want an extra Id column you can improve performance by manually defining an index on category_id and post_id. There is no benefit of having an extra key column though and this is generally a bad practice.

Comment: I agree with @Glenn Vandamme, there is no point in having an additional column especially if it is going to be a big table with a million rows. Any columns that you add to a table take up space. When querying these tables that data is pulled as well which causing slower queries. You will also need an additional index which will need to be updated every time you do an insert.

Answer (score 2):

not having id is good, but when you care about ordering by the pivot table you will need to have id or timestamp in pivot table