# Select specific data from main table on joining in MySQL

Tags: mysql

[image]
I have Two tables.Table one is the master table containing name of some products, table two save the product assigned to specific users.Then i need to get the product list from the master table(table 1) which is not added under the user in table 2.
above image shows the table structure.

So when I chose user 11 its should not how the product_name C.
How can I write the MySQL query for this.

Comment: You should not put the product name in your pivot table. Same goes with the primary key on that table. Make the primary key a compound key of both the product id and user id. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153990/is-there-any-benefit-to-having-an-auto-incrementing-primary-key-in-a-mysql-pivot. In most cases, pivot tables should only have 2 columns.

Comment: My actual table doesn't have the product name in table2. i just keep it to make my question more understanding

Answer (score 2):

You may try this query

```
SELECT table1.product_name FROM `table1`
INNER JOIN table2 on table2.p_id = table1.p_id
WHERE table2.user_id = 11
```

Comment: Can you please help me to get the unused product names

Comment: sure, anter two more product name in table1 then try this query: SELECT table1.product_name FROM `table1`
LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.p_id = table1.p_id
WHERE table2.user_id IS NULL

Comment: It only gives the list of used product

Comment: am sorry their was mistake in my part...i need to get the  unused product list for specific users

Comment: plus 1 for sql fiddle

Answer (score 1):

I guees below query should work.

```
SELECT p1.p_id,p1.product_name FROM table_1 AS p1
INNER JOIN table_2 AS p2
ON p2.p_id = p1.p_id
WHERE p2.user_id = '11'
```

Comment: YA this work fine,but it shows the used product. can you make changes tho get the unused product name

Comment: which table contains the used product data ?

Comment: second table...i got the answer ..thankyou for your help